# Android insert contact with Intents.Insert not works

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm trying to develop a app in this I need to access the contacts to add phone number with name. for this I'm using following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, "Silambarasan");
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, 9876543210L);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code opens the add contact screen, but in the screen only name "Silambarasan" sent from this code. Phone "Number :9876543210L "is not passed.

Do I use correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From [ContactsContract.Intents.Insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html) documentation

> ***`public static final String PHONE`*** : Added in API level 5
>
> *The extra field for the contact phone number.*
>
> **Type:** *String* // Clears that you need to pass String value for this extra
>
> **Constant Value:** *"phone"*

---

***Simply pass number as String into extra that will work.***

*So change* 
`intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, 9876543210L);`

with

```
 intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, "9876543210");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass it like this?

```
intent.putExtra("nameForThisExtra", "Silambarasan")
intent.putExtra("nameForThisExtra", "9876543210L");
intent.putExtra("nameForThisExtra", Phone.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

and call it in the ohter activity like this:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameForThisExtra");
String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameForThisExtra");
```

That should work.

The first parameter is the name you want to give this Extra, the second parameter the value.